# How to retrieve more than 30000 rows from database table using laravel 5 query?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I am unable to retrieve more than 30000 rows from a database table using laravel 5 query. The server is returning an error saying "500 Internal Server Error".

My query is as below:

```
DB::table('tablename')
->select('A','B','C','D')
->get();
```

Please help.

Comment: From database side 30000 rows is not a big deal. So from database side everything should go well. Independent if you choose something MySQL, Postgres or anything else. Can u put your table schema and your code?

Comment: You need to do some digging in the webserver's log files and get the proper error message because in this format your question cannot be properly answered. Obviously we can guess (script timeout or exhaust of a resource), but this is not the point of SO.

Answer (score 0):

If It retrieves fewer records (let's say 1000), it is not the code. In that it is very likely that the server is exhausting the memory allocated or that the processor is too slow to handle that kind of computation. It sounds almost like a lolwut moment, but you would be surprised!